# Isogonality in a complete quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

> If $ABCD$ is a quadrilateral inscribed in circle $\omega$ with $E=AD\cap BC$ and $M,N$ midpoints of $AC$ and $BD$, prove that $EM$ and $EN$ are isogonal with respect to $AEB$. (Otherwise show that$\angle DEN=\angle MEC$).

I hunt for geometry properties as recreational activity and while drawing diagram I was noticed that this appears true. I attempted the use of Newton's Line through $MN$, to no avail. I am not that great at projecting geometry, please help! Thanks to all who can help.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Quadrilateral ABCD]

Observe that, $\triangle ACE\sim \triangle BDE$.

$\Rightarrow   \frac{CA}{CE}=\frac{BD}{DE}$

$\Rightarrow   \frac{CM}{CE}=\frac{ND}{DE}$      [Dividing both sides by 2]

$\Rightarrow   \triangle MCE\sim \triangle NDE$

$\Rightarrow   \boxed {\angle MEC=\angle DEN}$